# How to change quarkus profile using environment variable?

Tags: quarkus

Right now i have application.yml with

```
smallrye:
  config:
    profile: prod, postgres
```

But i want to do something like it

```
profiles:
  active:
    - ${APP_PROFILE:prod}
    - ${APP_DATABASE_PROFILE:postgres}
```

How can i do this in quarkus?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the active profile with the environment variable `QUARKUS_PROFILE=PROFILE_NAME` or via a system property with `-Dquarkus.profile=PROFILE_NAME`. You can also specify multiple profiles in these formats separated by commas.